# react-devtools : TimeoutError: Timed out while inspecting element 2

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

An occasional problem, and has not been repeated.
Has anyone experienced the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste any text in your question instead of using a screenshot. It may help to check out [ask] and how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, here are some steps that might help you:

1. Remove react-devetools and reinstall
2. On your browser -> go to extension settings -> enable ***"Allow access to file URLs"*** [image]

Comment: Step 2 was all I needed.